# Can you reduce a vehicle's rev limit?

Tags: xc90, reprogram

2006 Volvo XC90 gives "no oil pressure" warning when revved above the red line for more than a second.

Following advice from a Volvo forum I used motor cleaner and changed the oil (twice) attempting to remove sludge.It got better after the first change but no difference after the second one. Once, after the warning light came on it made some bangy clanky sounds that I didn't notice until I slowed down and rolled down the windows. So I don't think it's a sensor issue. Anyways turning the car off for ten seconds makes the issue go away.

Instead of fixing that I just want to lower the rpm limit. Is that possible?

Comment: An alternative solution to lowering the rev limiter... If you're starving it for oil above red line, then you might consider a bigger oil pan which holds more oil, or a dry-sump type oil system. If the engine looses oil pressure, then the protective layer of oil between the bearing surfaces is reduced, and you can do massive damage to the engine.

Comment: Why are you revving it above the redline in the first place? At the risk of stating the obvious this sounds like something of an XY problem.

Comment: Are you trying to do this: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/60027/is-revving-the-engine-to-redline-on-idle-at-morning-bad/60028 ...if yes, then stop doing it!

Comment: There may be a problem with the oil pickup strainer being partially blocked.  Moving the rev limiter won't fix this.

Comment: I'm not trying to fix it. No, I'm not trying to do what that other question was talking about where every morning he revs up his engine really high in his truck. Did you read either question? I want to lower the max rev limit on this car by having someone reprogram the computer. I'm trying to figure out how to make that happen.

Comment: I would self-impose a limit of 500 rpm below the redline.  Or, you could fix the problem properly.